# No data in Azure SQL after importing bacpac file

Tags: import, azure-sql-database, azure

I've created a bacpac file of my database for transfer to Azure. The file is uploaded and imported successfully but there's no data in the imported database. What did I do wrong? There don't seem to be options about with or without data. The structure did end up correctly in the database.

I verified the bacpac by importing it locally.

Comment: What is the database size show in the portal, does it compare to the database you imported locally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: It wasn't finished importing yet.

I found out - it was impatience. As soon as I could access the DB and see the structure I thought the import process was done. But it turned out it was still importing. So good to know that you can access it before it's ready. (In hindsight there was sort of an indicator, while it was still importing it showed 1 additional table, something with Transaction... bla).

However, I could have known as I found out that there would still be an 'Importing...' item in the Notifications panel in the Azure portal during the import. It doesn't show that on any of the blades however.

Comment: I have found out that patience in Azure is a virtue;  I see something similar when I use a runbook to create database A as a copy of A_template.  There is a definite time lag between completion and true usability.

Comment: you can actually watch the database increase in size. but a database that appears over time seems to be the least databasey thing you'd want but I assume you can't make changes until it is finished?

Comment: Well, my database shows as online in azure, after import, within less than a minute from submitting it for review (to whom?). I don't think I am impatient when I see that next to a DB name... In addition to that, DB properties show 40MB size.... I guess I need to keep looking for solution to my problem...